# Mac OS not booting after windows Install on dual boot

Tags: windows-10, macos, multi-boot, macos-highsierra

Recently I have dual booted a Mac with windows **Without Using BootCamp Assistant.  Instead I used media creation tool on an another PC to download Windows 10 ISO file and had created bootable pen drive using *Rufus*. Smoothly, plugging in the pen drive and installing Windows from it.

Everything worked alright till there but as I tried booting using Mac I was unable to do so and was presented with similar screen:

[image]

I can seamlessly boot to windows but I want to boot into mac as well to defend the whole purpose of *dual booting*?!

I have tried everything that could work with the help of the internet but nothing seems to work out! NowI am really desperate to have it solved:

Things you should know:
- I don't have bootcamp assistant on my windows
- I am unable to re-install Mac using the recovery mode
- I am running High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: hold down alt whilst switching on - keep holding until the screen changes. What do you see?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I see the boot menu where I have option to choose between Operating systems ie: Windows & Macintosh. When I click on the Macintosh Icon, Mac loads up for a while and then the 'No Entry' symbol appears (The one with the image link on the question)  https://derflounder.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/screen-shot-2014-08-11-at-9-02-14-pm.png

Comment: You need to get a copy of your OS on USB stick - I have never successfully installed boot-camp yet - It works for a while then breaks. If you get your OS on USB then boot from that you will be able to repair whatever has broken.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas thanks! I will surely try that. Can you give me a quick rundown where to download mac os from ? How to boot ? Do i have do it similarly to what i have done with windows. Meaning downloading OS iso then creating bootable pendrive and then booting ?

Comment: In short, whatever you did to get Windows on there has blown away your macOS install. How you did it & how you get it back will probably depend on what machine, OS, & date of your last backup. BTW, I've had Boot Camp on my Macs for over 10 years, not lost one yet. I currently have 2 BC partitions, though I have one hidden from BC to not confuse the system.

Comment: You will need access to another mac - Plenty of tutorials online concerning getting sierra on USB - To start you need to download your copy on the App store, get an 8gb USB stick, then use DiskmakerX or a similar utility.

Comment: Mac uses a different partition table than Windows (GUID Partition Table (GPT) versus Master Boot Record(MBR)).  It sounds like you nerfed the GPT.  Your first step is to determine what kind of boot record exists.  You might have to re-install MacOSx and I'd suggest using BootCamp as it will accomodate the different partition types.

Comment: @hogstorm MacOS is still there in partition its just I am unable to boot through it. Its is visible in the disk utility

Answer (score 1):

> **If you can't start up from macOS Recovery**
>
> Newer Mac computers and some older Mac computers automatically try to
>   start up from macOS Recovery over the Internet when unable to start up
>   from the built-in recovery system. When that happens, you see a
>   spinning globe instead of an Apple logo during startup. To manually
>   start up from macOS Recovery over the Internet, hold down
>   Option-Command-R or Shift-Option-Command-R at startup.
>
> If you still can't start up from macOS Recovery, and you have a Mac
>   that is able to start up completely, you might be able to create an
>   external Mac startup disk to start up from instead.

From: Apple Support - 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314